# First steps to a CAS

Tags: prolog

I tried to run this code:

```
eq(mul(a,b),mul(c,b)).
eq(X,Y) :- eq(mul(X,Z),mul(Y,Z))
```

with the query: eq (X, Y)

I expected the results:

```
X=mul(a,b),Y=(mul(c,b)) and X=a,Y=c
```

But I just got the first one.

Comment: cannot reproduce: I get `X=mul(a,b)` `Y=mult(c,b)` first and `X=a` `Y=c` next (p.s.: merry christmas to you)

Comment: if you get a solution, instead of <Enter>, try pressing `h` for help to see what you can do. Usually, pressing `;` or <Space> should give you the next solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
eq(mul(a, b), mul(c, b)).

equal(X,Y) :-
    eq(mul(X, Z), mul(Y, Z)).
```

Note that I have used different predicate names, to prevent a common mistake of infinite recursion/looping if a predicate (e.g. "eq") is calling itself.

Result in swi-prolog:

```
?- equal(X, Y).
X = a,
Y = c.
```

This rule would be wrong:

```
eq(X,Y) :- eq(mul(X,Z),mul(Y,Z)).
```

because X cannot be simultaneously mul(something) and part of the same something inside the mul(). Also, it falls into the trap of infinite recursion/looping.